# split a string with commas inside of a list python

Tags: python, list, split

I have this list

```
l = [[hello,world],[i need help, python]] 
l [0] = [hello, world] 
l [1] = [i need help, python]
```

I need to split `l[0]` and `l[1]` by commas, but I don't know how to do it
because `"hello, world"` and `"i need help, python"` are strings.

Can anybody help me on this please!

Comment: They are not, currently, strings. Can you at least please include the quotes? And what would the expected output be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive method I use for problems like this...

```
def explode(sep,x):
    if isinstance(x,(str,unicode)): return x.split(sep)
    elif isinstance(x,list): return [explode(sep,each) for each in x]
    elif isinstance(x,dict):return {key:explode(sep,x[key]) for key in x}
    else: raise ValueError("function doesn't support",type(x))

l = [["hello,world"],["i need help, python"]] 
l = explode(",",l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the list and split each entry using `myString.split(",")`

Comment: And then what? The OP hasn't exactly specified where the results of the split should go..

Comment: He has problem splitting, I assume he knows what to do with the results after that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to loop over list:

```
>>> l = [['hello,world'],['i need help, python']] 
>>> for x in l:
...     print x[0]       # if you sung python 3x print(x[0])
... 
hello,world
i need help, python
```

if you want to split string:

```
>>> for x in l:
...     print x[0].split(',')
... 
['hello', 'world']
['i need help', ' python']
```

read about [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: then he can add split x[0].split()

Comment: And then what? Should the original lists be altered? Stored in a new, flat list? There is too much detail lacking.

Comment: I did, because your initial edit failed to address the question.

Comment: OP is not clear so i was covering all the aspect :)

Comment: Thanks Hackaholic, that's what I've done and works.

Comment: And sorry for not to explain myself better. But what I wanted it's what hackaholic explained. Thanks